# In a 3D density field $\sigma(t),$ why do we take the product $\mathrm{d}t \cdot \sigma(t)$ for the probability of a ray hitting a particle?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, probability

I'm reading [Volume Reading Digest (for NeRF)](https://arxiv.org/abs/2209.02417) and am having trouble understanding something in this section:

> Let the density field $\sigma(\mathbf{x})$, with $\mathbf{x} \in \mathbb{R}^3$ indicate the differential likelihood of a ray hitting a particle (i.e. the probability of hitting a particle while travelling an infinitesimal distance).
>
> We reparameterize the density along a given ray $\mathbf{r} = (\mathbf{o}, \mathbf{d})$ as a scalar function $\sigma(t),$ since any point $\mathbf{x}$ along the ray can be written as $\mathbf{r}(t) = \mathbf{o} + t \mathbf{d}.$
>
> Density is closely tied to the transmittance function $T(t),$ which indicates the probability of a ray traveling over the interval $[0, t)$ without hitting any particles.
>
> Then the probability $T(t + \mathrm{d}t)$ of *not* hitting a particle when taking a differential step $\mathrm{d}t$ is equal to $T(t),$ the likelihood of the ray reaching $t,$ times $(1 − \mathrm{d}t \cdot \sigma(t)),$ the probability of not hitting anything during the step:
>
> $$T(t + \mathrm{d}t) = T(t) \cdot (1 - \mathrm{d}t \cdot \sigma(t))$$

It would be more intuitive to me if we said that $$T(t + \mathrm{d}t) = T(t) \cdot (1 - \sigma(t + \mathrm{d}t)),$$ i.e. if we said that the probability of a ray *not* hitting a particle while traversing a distance of $t + \mathrm{d}t$ from the ray origin $\mathbf{o}$ into the ray direction $\mathbf{d}.$

It's not clear to me, however, why we use the product $\mathrm{d}t \cdot \sigma(t)$ for the probability of hitting a particle during that infinitesimal step $\mathrm{d}t$ beyond the point $\mathbf{r}(t).$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, following your logic, the probability should be $T(t)(1-\int_t^{t+dt}\sigma(\tau)d\tau))$ since we need to subtract the accumulated density. Now, because we are dealing with infintesimals, $\int_t^{t+dt}\sigma(\tau)d\tau\approx dt\sigma(t)$

Comment: Ah yes, thank you.